# Why i can't add element using list reference which returned by method

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am having error when i add elements using list reference which returned by method.

**Dummy.java**

```
package firstPro;

import java.util.List;

public class Dummy {

    private List<String> names;

    public Dummy(List<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return this.names;
    }

}
```

**main**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class count {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dummy obj = new Dummy(Arrays.asList("foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4", "foo5"));
        List<String> name = obj.getNames();
        name.add("foo6");
        System.out.println(name);

    }

}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at firstPro.count.main(count.java:13)
```

I know i can get rid of this error by adding

> new ArrayList(obj.getNames())

My Question is why i can't use that referece as raw?

Comment: Note that it's often not desirable to allow users of your class to have direct access to internal state. Returning `Collections.unmodifiableList(names)` allows you to keep control of the contents of that list (although that would also cause an exception to be thrown if you tried to add to it). Better to provide an adder method on your class.

Comment: tnx for the useful advice sir i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.asList("foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4", "foo5")` creates a fixed sized list, so you can't add/remove elements to it (only modify the existing elements or replace the elements in the existing indices).

You can use:

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4", "foo5"))
```

to support adding new elements.

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDoc of [`Arrays.asList(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)), emphasis mine:

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array.

You can make `Dummy` handle modifications by making it copy the values from the received list into a new `ArrayList` instance,
by changing its constructor:

```
public Dummy(List<String> names) {
    this.names = new ArrayList<>(names);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)'s documentation:

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array.

Since the returned `List` has a fixed-size, it does not support the `add` operation, and calling it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` as you've noticed.